# Is there any battery that can provide 2 billion coulombs of charge?

Tags: battery

What battery can provide 2 billion coulombs?

Comment: You need to be more specific with your question. In theory, any battery of sufficient size can "provide" a charge of 2 billion Coulombs. Are you asking for a certain type of battery? Are you looking for the necessary size of the battery?

Comment: @Andrew Thank you. Any type of battery. Do you know any able to provide such charge?

Comment: You can create any coulomb by transforming the current to a lower voltage. So the current will increase. But it would require a dc/ac conversion for the transformation, or you would have high losses.

Comment: 2 GC at what voltage? Did you work out the kWh capacity you are seeking. Why are you asking the question? You've had five of your six questions closed on this site. This should be a clear indication to you that there is something wrong with your questions. You need to edit them to give some context (why you are asking), what your research has revealed and where you are stuck.

Comment: Maybe this battery? https://www.greentechmedia.com/amp/article/ls-power-energizes-worlds-biggest-battery-near-san-diego-just-in-time-for-heatwave

Answer (score 1):

2 billion coulombs (small 'c' when spelt out) = 2 GC (assuming you mean 1 billion = 10<sup>9</sup>, an American billion).

From $ Q = I \times t $ we can say that 2 GC = 2 GAs (giga-ampere-seconds).

$ 2 \ \text {GAs} = \frac 2 {3600} \ \text {GAh} = 0.55 \ \text{MAh} = 550 \ \text {kAh}$

So, you just need 1,000 × 550 Ah batteries in parallel.